# Extracting ping times and prefixing with time stamp

Tags: bash, sed, awk, ping

I am trying to extract the ping times in a more data-friendly format. My goal is to turn something like this:

```
64 bytes from arn06s02-in-f0.1e100.net (173.194.32.32): icmp_seq=59 ttl=54 time=31.8 ms
```

into something like:

```
1361999357 31.8
```

Where the first number comes from $(date +%s) and the second number is the 8th column from the ping command.

I would like to be able to run this for a long time and get a long, two-column list of timestamps and ping times.

**Timestamp**
I have the timestamp working with the following:

```
ping google.com | while read line; do echo "$(date +%s) $line"; done
```

But when I try to add sed, awk, or cut into the pipeline to get just the time I end up with no output!

I'm not very familiar with sed or awk, though I'm certain they must be the right tools for the job. My attempts have resulted in no output.. I think it is because awk is expecting an EOF before passing the output to the next piped program?

Thanks!

Comment: awk and sed both do line-by-line processing. if they don't do output, then you're not processing the input right and both think there's nothing to output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ ping google.com | awk -F'[ =]' 'NR>1{print system("echo -n $(date +%s)"), $11}'
```

Short & efficient, no ? =) And no buffering problems occurs...

Note : `system("")` can be used as a hack to avoid buffering.

Comment: Actually, I cannot seem to redirect the output to a file with `> f`. Do you know why?

Comment: Cheers! That solves the file issue. I also just noticed that the 'date' command is not changing. It gives the same time for each ping.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate your time :) You are an awk genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ping -c 1 google.com | grep "bytes from" | while read line; do echo "$(date +%s) $line"; done | awk '{print $1 " " $8}' | sed 's,time=,,'
```

Note that if you leave off the '-c', there's a certain amount of buffering that happens before you get any output.  Leaving the '-c' lets you see the results more quickly and to verify that things are working.

Comment: This works! Except the $8 needs to be $9 in awk to account for the added timestamp. How large is the buffer when -c is not specified? It has been running for a while still.. ideally this script should flush the buffer after each ping.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different...

```
( date '+%s' ; ping -c 1 google.com; ) | sed -ne '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/h;/ bytes from /{s/^.*time=\([0-9.]*\).*/ \1/;H;g;s/\n//;p;}'
```

Result: 1362002815 7.52

Comment: I need to be able to run ping without specifying `-c`. But thanks!